# Multiple devices on mdio bus

Tags: embedded-linux, kernel-module

I have multiple devices on MDIO bus (one AR8035 PHY, and 6 DP83849IFVS dual PHYs). The bus is connected to AM335x SoC with linux 4.14.40. Davinchi_mdio scans bus and finds all devices and attaches driver I think for AR8035. How can I access this bus via mdio? I want to write stand-lone (not PHY driver) kernel module, that can simply access mdio bus? How can I do that? I wanted to do that with  phy_write/phy_read but I can't get struct phy_device* from my kernel module. How can I get struct phy_device* from the name of the interface ("eth0"). Will it be safe in terms of locks/mutaxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have an subsystem for MDIO controller, then I can think of implementing an UIO driver for MDIO interface, which deals with read and write.

UIO driver is safe when compared to the messy kernel driver and complete control will be with the user application which uses that UIO.

**
*Each UIO device is accessed through a device file and several sysfs attribute files. The device file will be called /dev/uio0 for the first device, and /dev/uio1, /dev/uio2 and so on for subsequent devices.

/dev/uioX is used to access the address space of the card. Just use mmap() to access registers or RAM locations of your card.

Interrupts are handled by reading from /dev/uioX. A blocking read() from /dev/uioX will return as soon as an interrupt occurs.*
**